# How to data-binding two variables in the same select

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this code here:

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <label for="field_type"><b>Type</b></label>
    <div class="input-icon right">
        <select required class="form-control"
                id="field_type"
                name="type"
                ng-model="vm.service.type"
                ng-options="serviceType.name as serviceType.name for serviceType in vm.servicetypes">
            <option></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="vm.service.type==null" class="form-group has-error">
        <p class="help-block" ng-show="vm.service.type==null" data-translate="entity.validation.required">
            This field is required.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The thing is...as i'm doing

> vm.service.type = serviceType.name

, i also wanna do

> vm.service.serviceTypeId = serviceType.id

...How do i do this only having this select field?

Comment: try calling a function on click of select option and assign these values inside the function

Comment: use ng-init for this

Comment: @user2427829 Thank You! I addapted your "solution" and it worked...thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on following example.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p>Select a car:</p>

<select ng-model="selectedCar" ng-options="x for (x, y) in cars">
</select>

<h1>You selected: {{selectedCar.brand}}</h1>
<h2>Model: {{selectedCar.model}}</h2>
<h3>Color: {{selectedCar.color}}</h3>

<p>Note that the selected value represents an object.</p>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.cars = {
        car01 : {brand : "Ford", model : "Mustang", color : "red"},
        car02 : {brand : "Fiat", model : "500", color : "white"},
        car03 : {brand : "Volvo", model : "XC90", color : "black"}
    }
});
</script>
```

find it here - http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_select_object_object

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I couldnt make it done by this way but i addapted a previous suggestion and it worked. Instead of getting a field of the object i got the entire object and saved it on aux variable. Before i did the save, i took that aux variable and put its fields on the correspondent fields of my object and it worked. Thanks!